# Best practice stop thread when finish processing queue

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, android-handler, android-thread

I'm trying to understand which would be the best practice to have a thread which ensures that the messages queued are executed in a synchronous way and it finishes itself once it hasn’t more messages to process.

I've been reading the documentation of Handler and ServiceExecutor and I found [ExecutorService's submit method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) returns a Future object from which I could call [Future.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) but then I would need another thread to be noticed when the execution of the Runnable has finished.
Also on [Executor's](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) doc they have a SerialExecutor example where I guess that I could check the size of the queue in order to finish the thread.

Honestly I think that there has to be a better way to achieve this behaviour, so I was wondering which is the best practice.

**Edit:**

I don't have all the messages at once, so I don't know when the thread will stop or until I want to force it to stop. If not, I'd like to keep running until it has finished processing all the messages.

Comment: If you already have all the messages, you can submit them all to a single threaded executor and shut it down right afterwards.

Comment: @Kayaman I forgot to mention that I don't have all the messages at once. So I might have to "start the thread" again if it has been stopped. But In case of receiving a message while another one it's being executed, I'd like to queue it. I edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: So you don't actually want to stop the thread at all then. This is not some start/stop thing where you save gas by shutting down the motor in the lights. If there's more messages coming, the thread isn't finished.

Comment: You say ```I don't have all the messages at once``` then ```I'd like to keep running until it has finished processing all the messages``` so you basically know in advance the number of tasks the executor would have to proceed, is that correct?

Comment: @Kayaman I get your point, but shouldn't I be concerned If repeated the same pattern in many places, holding threads which might or might not have work to do, but they keep consuming resources?.

Comment: @aiqency no, I don't know in advance the number of tasks that will be executed. So my intent was to avoid wasting resources.

Comment: @strok_777 you're prematurely optimizing. If the thread has nothing to do it'll be waiting and not consuming resources. Optimizing requires knowledge. Don't try to optimize unless you know how, especially by guessing, as that's a surefire way to get bad results.

Comment: @Kayaman ok. Thanks for the help. I wasn't sure if it was worth or there was a better practice to do this sort of things.

Comment: Maybe you can try out rxjava

Comment: Provide a thread that receives its messages from a request mailbox (or blocks while no message is pending. It shall process each message it gets out of the mailbox before trying to receive the next one. Everytime no message is pending, It will be blocked (forever). Is it that you can detect if one message will be the last one, so you'd like the thread to shut down afterwards? Then, I'd propose to enhance the message format by one extra "EOF" message/request type that tells the worker thread that this was the last one, and it shall close.